# Handling txt file and data structures

Tags: c, data-structures, file-handling

I found this exercise where i had to create a data structures, read some inputs, store the inputs on the "appropriate" data structure and then print them on a txt file. I managed to create the program but i'm not really sure i did it properly, since i'm new to data structures, is it storing every input in the data structure before printing it?

Last question: i was looking forward to adding a function to order the hotel list according to the stars number, so if an hotel has 5 stars, it will be at the top of the list. Is it possible to do that? Can i do that with arrays?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct inputs {
   char nome[30];
   char via[30]; 
   char stars[30];
   int num;
};

int main(void)
{  

   struct inputs inputs = {"", "", ""};

   FILE *cfPtr; // cfPtr = clients.txt file pointer   
   // fopen opens file. Exit program if unable to create file 
   if ((cfPtr = fopen("clients.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
      puts("File could not be opened");
   } 
   else { 
      puts("Enter the account, name, and balance.");
      puts("Enter EOF to end input.");
      printf("%s", "? ");


      //scanf("%[^\n]s%[^\n]s%[^\n]s", inputs.via, inputs.nome, inputs.stars);



      fgets(inputs.nome, 30, stdin);
      inputs.nome[strcspn(inputs.nome,"\n")] = '\0';
      fgets(inputs.via, 30, stdin);
      inputs.via[strcspn(inputs.via,"\n")] = '\0';
      fgets(inputs.stars, 30, stdin);
      inputs.stars[strcspn(inputs.stars,"\n")] = '\0';

      inputs.num = strlen(inputs.stars);


      //printf("%s%s%s", inputs.nome, inputs.via, inputs.stars);

      // write account, name and balance into file with fprintf
      while (!feof(stdin)) {
           fprintf(cfPtr, "%s; %s; %s; %d\n", inputs.nome, inputs.via, inputs.stars, inputs.num);

           /*scanf("%[^\n]s", inputs.via);
           scanf("%[^\n]s", inputs.nome);
           scanf("%[^\n]s", inputs.stars);*/
           fgets(inputs.nome, 30, stdin);
           inputs.nome[strcspn(inputs.nome,"\n")] = '\0';
           fgets(inputs.via, 30, stdin);
           inputs.via[strcspn(inputs.via,"\n")] = '\0';
           fgets(inputs.stars, 30, stdin);
           inputs.stars[strcspn(inputs.stars,"\n")] = '\0';
           inputs.num = strlen(inputs.stars);

      }

      fclose(cfPtr); // fclose closes file   
   } 
}
```

Comment: `feof()` :: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/905902

Comment: Thank you, i'm going to edit it!

Comment: "appropriated" data structures? Or "appropriate" data structures?

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016696/writing-strings-from-data-structures-on-file? Or a follow-up?

Comment: It's a follow up